# Javascript return and ternary operator with var, possible?

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry if this question is a duplicate, but I really don't know how to search for it. This question may sound "odd" for an expert JavaScript programmer, but I'm not.

I'm basically trying to do a "one line return", without wasting another line of code. I **know** that it's not good, and the following it's not code for production:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

module.exports = function (digits) {
    if (!/^\d+$/.test(digits)) return undefined;

    var precomp = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9];

    var sum = _.reduce(digits.toString(), function (mem, dgt, idx) {
        return mem + (idx % 2 == 0 ? parseInt(dgt) : precomp[dgt]);
    }, 0);

    return (var mod = sum % 10 == 0) ? 0 : 10 - mod; // Error
};
```

The last line throws an error because the `var` keyword. I remember doing sometimes the same in PHP.

**EDIT**: I don't think so "hard" to read the question before answer... I'm asking if it's possible, I'm not saying it's right, good looking, or whatever.

(By the way this is the luhn check calculation)

Comment: I'm just wondering, are you downvoting all those legitimate and still correct answers?

Comment: btw: you'll have to put `mod = sum % 10` in parentheses otherwise it won't work because `mod` would be the result of the `==` operator and thus a boolean.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VariableDeclaration are not expressions. Just declare it before.

```
module.exports = function (digits) {
    var mod;

    // ...

    return (mod = sum % 10 ...
}
```

Comment: If you really don't want another line for some reason, add the declaration of `mod` to one of your other `var` lines: `var precomp = [...], mod;`

Comment: @Gremo I'm not clear how this fails to answer your question. The first sentence here addresses your question directly and says it's not possible in very direct language-specification terms, and the rest of the answer suggests a perfectly suitable workaround.

Comment: Not possible to declare the `var` just after the return statement, and using it in the `return` statement. If you are 100% sure that's not possible, just say it in your answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Gremo Sure that's possible, the declaration will be hoisted to the top of the function anyway.

Comment: @Gremo It's *not* possible; that's what this answer says. According to the ECMAScript spec, a [`VariableStatement`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2) is not valid in the first part of a [`ConditionalStatement`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12), which must be a [`EqualityExpression`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9). That's exactly what this answer is getting at with its first sentence (i.e., what the OP is trying to do is *not possible*), but it's not clear unless you know where to look in the spec.

Comment: @apsillers Sorry, I misread the OP's comment, I thought he was talking about placing `var` in the *line* after the return statement.

Comment: @bfavaretto Oh, I see the confusion -- in any case, I'll keep the comment since it may be useful clarification for the OP.

Comment: I certainly didn't thought that answer would bring such discussion, haha. Thanks @apsillers :)

Answer (score 3):

I think the only way for you to do this is:

```
var mod = sum % 10;
return (mod == 0) ? 0 : 10 - mod;
```

Who cares about one extra line of code? Why does that matter?

Comment: I made it clear in the question about not asking WHY i want to write code like this.

Comment: Well whatever the reason is, it's not possible.

Comment: @gremo No you didn't. You said, quote, "I'm basically trying to do a "one line return", without wasting another line of code". You didn't say why that would be "wasting" another line of code, and instead you just said "it's not prod code" which isn't an excuse for building bad habits.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're trying too hard here.  Just move `var mod` before the return statement.  You're NOT going to be struck dead by the software gods for having one more line of code here.  Clarity over conciseness.

Comment: Same comment as below: I made it clear in the question about not asking WHY i want to write code like this. I want to know if it's possible, because (say) PHP will let do it.

Comment: Fair enough; it's one of those curious things we all encounter when switching between languages.

Comment: Javascript isn't very close to PHP syntax, just because PHP will let you do it doesn't mean Javascript will. Just accept that you need two lines for this in JS.

Comment: @SpikeX I'm not saying that it should. I'm actually enjoying javascript.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is not PHP

```
var mod = sum % 10;
return (mod === 0) ? 0 : 10 - mod;
```

Answer (score 2):

I see you don't like any of the answers so far. One way to avoid declaring the variable first is this, which you probably won't like either:

```
return (sum % 10 == 0) ? 0 : 10 - (sum % 10);
```

This doesn't require an extra line, but it does require an extra mod.

---

Another option, which might make the code extemely confusing, is to add a dummy argument to the function:

```
module.exports = function (digits, mod) {
    /* code */
    return (mod = sum % 10) == 0 ? 0 : 10 - mod; // Error
};
```

Comment: +1 while it does perform the same operation twice (bad), it does answer OP's question (good).

Comment: Yes, that's why I said the OP probably wouldn't like it (I certainly don't).

Comment: Because no one seems to understand the question. It's so obvious that I would need to add `var` on top of my script.

Comment: OP seems to have thrown out all reason and logic and is quite hellbent on putting this on one line, so he probably will like it. :)

Comment: @bfavaretto already thought about your solution, of course I don't like it. But I didn't downvoted you.

Comment: @Gremo Added another hack.

Comment: @SpikeX I edit your answer by mistake, sorry. Rolled it back already.

Comment: @bfavaretto funny but ugly! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't use `sum` for any other purpose, you could move the `%` operator up, doing:

```
var _ = require('underscore');

module.exports = function (digits) {
    if (!/^\d+$/.test(digits)) return undefined;

    var precomp = [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9];

    var sum = _.reduce(digits.toString(), function (mem, dgt, idx) {
        return mem + (idx % 2 == 0 ? parseInt(dgt) : precomp[dgt]);
    }, 0) % 10;

    return (sum == 0) ? 0 : 10 - sum; // Error
};
```